# How can I remove the letter-spacing on the last letter of an <a> tag in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm a newbie.

I'm trying to remove the letter-spacing on the last letter for an a tag I styled into a button and centred on the page.

```css
body {
  background-color: #1E1E96;
}
a {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.btn-wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 100px auto;
}
.btn-wrapper a {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 10px;
  padding: 15px 40px;
  border: solid 2px #FFF;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="btn-wrapper">
    <a href="#">Change Colour</a>
  </div>

</body>
```

I tried

```
    .btn-wrapper a {
      margin-right: -10px;
    }
```

and

```
    .btn-wrapper a {
      text-indent: 10px;
    }
```

with no joy.

I am loath to put a span on the last letter.

The above suggestions I found on Stack Overflow.

Can someone please explain what's going on with my code and help find a solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems like a very odd request. What is the purpose?

Comment: @Paulie_D the purpose is to truly center the text. If you create a fiddle with an extra border, you'll see the `letter-spacing` adds a space at the end of all characters including the last one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could wrap the entire text part of the link in a span and use the `margin-right: -10px` technique to get this done.

```css
body {
  background-color: #1E1E96;
}
a {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.btn-wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 100px auto;
}
.btn-wrapper a {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 10px;
  padding: 15px 40px;
  border: solid 2px #FFF;
}
.btn-wrapper a span {
  margin-right: -10px;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="btn-wrapper">
    <a href="#"><span>Change Colour</span></a>
  </div>

</body>
```

**Edit :**

Browsers have bugs.

Firefox bug is https://bugzil.la/299943 and the one for Chrome is https://crbug.com/267056.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply incorporate the displacement inside padding with:
`padding: 15px 30px 15px 40px;`             // *no <span>s required*

Comment: this should be the accepted (up voted) answer. Plus it's a one line, no &lt;span&gt; added solution.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try change padding, so instead of 40px right use 30px, which is 40px - 10px letter-spacing.

```
.btn-wrapper a {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 10px;
  padding: 15px 30px 15px 40px;
  border: solid 2px #FFF;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<body>

  <div class="btn-wrapper">
    <a href="#">Change</a>
  </div>

  <style>
    body {
      background-color: #1E1E96;
    }
    a {
      font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      color: #FFF;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 12px;
    }
    .btn-wrapper {
      text-align: center;
      margin: 100px auto;
    }
    .btn-wrapper a {
      text-transform: uppercase;
      text-align: center;
      letter-spacing: 10px;
      padding: 15px 40px;
      padding-right: 30px;
      border: solid 2px #FFF;
    }
  </style>
</body>
```

Edited the padding and thats it :D decreased right padding of `<a></a>` to 30

Answer (score 0):

Use like this
    
    body {
      background-color: #1E1E96;
    }
    a {
      font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      color: #FFF;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 12px;

```
}
.btn-wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 100px auto;
}
.btn-wrapper a {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 10px;
  padding: 15px 40px;
  border: solid 2px #FFF;
}
.btn-wrapper a span {
  margin-right: -10px;
letter-spacing:10px;
}
</style>
<body>

  <div class="btn-wrapper">
    <a href="#"><span>Change Colour</span></a>
  </div>

</body>
```