# How to fix uneven padding in a button

Tags: css, sass

This is an insanely basic question but for the life of me I can't figure it out. I'm creating a button class and no matter what I do, there's extra space to the bottom and right of the text.

Tried altering `line-height`, `border-box`, `margin`s, `display`, `text-align` and some others.

```css
.button {
  font-family: 'helvetica';
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #000;
  margin: 0px;
  position: relative;
  letter-spacing: .4em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: $secondary-color;
  border: 4px solid #000;
  padding: .3em .75em;
  margin: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
   -webkit-transition: all .25s ease-in-out;


}

.button:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #000;
  }
```

```html
<a href="ProjectPage.html" class="button">project</a>
```

Just trying to get an evenly padded button that will resize to the text content.

Comment: Hi, welcome! Can you reproduce it in a [snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/), jsbin.com or some other tools? Also, which browser are you using?

Comment: Sorry, new to stack. Just edited the post with a sippet. I'm using chrome and safari. in the snippet it seems way more centered vertically, but it still seems to have more space on the right. I'm also not sure if it's because I'm using helvetica in the example and a google font in my code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I remove the letter-spacing on the last letter of an <a> tag in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37678137/how-can-i-remove-the-letter-spacing-on-the-last-letter-of-an-a-tag-in-css)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Although [the spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-text-3/#letter-spacing-property) says `letter-spacing` shouldn't be added at the end of the line, it seems it is added regardless. You can use this `padding` instead to "undo" it:

```
padding: .3em calc(.74em - .4em) .3em .75em;
```

or equivalently

```
padding: .3em .35em .3em .75em;
```

```css
.b1 {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: .3em .75em;
  letter-spacing: .4em;
}
.b2 {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: .3em calc(.75em - .4em) .3em .75em;
  letter-spacing: .4em;
}
```

```html
<span class="b1">FOO</span>
<span class="b2">FOO</span>
```

Comment: This seems to be working for me! Works fine with standard fonts, but the google font still has extra bottom padding. Taking the same approach and subtracting some from that as well works!

Answer (score 0):

this is happening because of `letter-spacing:0.4em` on your last letter to remove this wrap last letter in `span` with `letter-spacing:0` like this:

```css
.button {
  font-family: 'helvetica';
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #000;
  margin: 0px;
  display:inline-block;
  align-items:center;
  position: relative;
  letter-spacing: .4em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 4px solid #000;
  padding: .3em .75em;
  margin: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
   -webkit-transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
}


.button:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #000;
  }
```

```html
<a href="ProjectPage.html" class="button">projec<span style="letter-spacing:0px;">t</span</a>
```